# Scroll API misses some documents

Tags: elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I am trying to get all the documents from multiple indexes with Scroll Api but it doesn't return all of them. I found a similar question but op was obviously missing first set of documents. Link to the question: [Elasticsearch Search Scroll API doesn't retrieve all the documents from an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60844667/elasticsearch-search-scroll-api-doesnt-retrieve-all-the-documents-from-an-index)

Here is my code:

```
//Code to get indexes

for (String indexName : indexNames) {
   final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(45L));
   SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indexName);
   searchRequest.scroll(scroll);
   SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

   QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
      .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery(sourceId, 2))
      .filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(date).gte(01-05-2021).lte(31-05-2021));
   searchSourceBuilder.query(query);
   searchSourceBuilder.size(10000);
   searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

   SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
   String scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
   SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

   List<Model> model = new ArrayList<>();      

   while(searchHits != null && searchHits.length > 0) {
      for (SearchHit document : searchHits){
         //add document to model list created above
         } //end of for loop

   // insert model list to database

   SearchScrollRequest searchScrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId);
   searchScrollRequest.scroll(scroll);
   searchResponse = client.scroll(searchScrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
   scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
   searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

   } //end of while loop

   ClearScrollRequest clear = new ClearScrollRequest();
   clear.addScrollId(scrollId);

} //end of for loop at the top
```

Total number of documents I should get is 115 millions but I am missing more than 2 millions documents. I repeatedly checked my code but no idea what I am missing.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem complete... where does `scroll` come from in the following statement `searchScrollRequest.scroll(scroll);` ?

Comment: From line under the first for loop:    
final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(45L));

Comment: Oops, my bad sorry. You don't see any errors while the scrolling is taking place, right? Something like "No context exception" or similar

Comment: No errors. It just starts and finishes no problem.